# vertical navbar buttons displaced by nav content

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've been trying to solve this for 2 days now and tried everything I can think of. Ive tried a thousand combos of position, display, and floats.

I am trying to make a vertical navigation bar in which the content of the navigation buttons comes out as a 2nd tier of vertical buttons and from the second set comes a 3rd tier of vertical buttons, etc.

My problem is that the 2nd tier of buttons displaces the buttons in 1st tier. Strangely the 3rd tier does not displace the 2nd or 1st tier.

I have attached a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DJunkin/9vm3km3p/179/).

```
<html>

  <head>
   <style>

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      clear: both;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      float: left;
      min-width: 100px;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }

    .dropdown-options {
      display: none;
      min-width: 160px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropbtncontent {
      min-width: 160px;
      border: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 2px;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 2px;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 160px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-options {
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-options:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 2px;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 2px;
      display: block;
    }

   </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown1</button>

      <div class="dropdown-options">
        <button class="dropbtncontent">Dropdown1.1</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-options">
        <button class="dropbtncontent">Dropdown1.2</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-options">
        <button class="dropbtncontent">Dropdown1.3</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown3</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link y</a>
        <a href="#">Link r</a>
        <a href="#">Link a4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown4</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Lin</a>
        <a href="#">Lin 2</a>
        <a href="#">Lk 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: _“Strangely the 3rd tier does not displace the 2nd or 1st tier.”_ - well that’s because you positioned 3rd tier absolutely, but with 2nd you didn’t. // This is rather terrible code btw. ... I would suggest you go read https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/building-accessible-menu-systems/ to find out how to implement something like this in a halfway decent manner.

Comment: @CBroe It probably is a terrible code. I started learning a month ago in my spare time. Thanks for the resource. Ill have a look through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect by changing your `.dropbox` class to this:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 5px;
    //new code below
    overflow:show;
    height: 50px;
}
```

The fixed height would cause some of the 2nd tier options to show until it reached the height. 
With that, by setting `overflow:show` you allow children to show even if they're bigger than it's parent size without affecting other elements.

Comment: Wow. That is it? The simplest thing. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, sometimes it's just better to ask someone to look with a different POV. Anyway I must tell you that the approach you're doing is not ideal. I saw your comment saying you just started, so I'll recommend you reading about each css property when in doubt, it can be extremely helpful in the current and future projects.